# NappDrawer widget fails to build android package and gives error

Tags: titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, slidingdrawer, titanium-modules, titanium-widgets

I am working on Titanium SDK and needs to implement slider style menu.

For this I found [NappDrawer](https://github.com/FokkeZB/nl.fokkezb.drawer) a useful widget and it successfully works on iOS devices and simulators. But when I tried to build the same package on Android devices, it gives me error and `'Unfortunately stopped'` alert message.

I have placed the code on [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwrEZRw3ujafeGxwU1pWZ0ZJeEk/edit?usp=sharing).
I have registered the same issue [here](https://github.com/FokkeZB/nl.fokkezb.drawer/issues/27) as well.

The error which I encounter is:

```
[INFO] :   Installing apk: /Users/paresh.thakor/Documents/Titanium Studio Workspace/TestingPull/build/android/bin/TestingPull.apk
[INFO] :   Installing app on device: Hudl HT7S3
[INFO] :   App successfully installed
[INFO] :   Starting app: com.investis.pullref/.TestingpullActivity
[INFO] :   Application pid: 21167
[INFO] :   Project built successfully in 38s 54ms
-- Start application log -----------------------------------------------------
[INFO] :   TiApplication: (main) [0,0] checkpoint, app created.
[INFO] :   TiApplication: (main) [49,49] Titanium 3.2.3 (2014/04/22 10:17 b958a70)
[INFO] :   I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 3.101MB for 432012-byte allocation
[INFO] :   TiApplication: (main) [291,340] Titanium Javascript runtime: v8
[INFO] :   TiRootActivity: (main) [0,0] checkpoint, on root activity create, savedInstanceState: null
[WARN] :   V8Object: Runtime disposed, cannot set property 'userAgent'
[INFO] :   I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 4.909MB for 1536016-byte allocation
[INFO] :   TiRootActivity: (main) [0,0] checkpoint, on root activity resume. activity = com.investis.pullref.TestingpullActivity@41bbfcb8
[WARN] :   dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418f5930)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication: (main) [143,143] Sending event: exception on thread: main msg:java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.investis.pullref/org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Unable to convert null; Titanium 3.2.3,2014/04/22 10:17,b958a70
[ERROR] :  TiApplication: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.investis.pullref/org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Unable to convert null
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication: Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Unable to convert null
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at org.appcelerator.titanium.util.TiConvert.toInt(TiConvert.java:407)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at dk.napp.drawer.Drawer.processProperties(Drawer.java:343)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollProxy.setModelListener(KrollProxy.java:1185)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at dk.napp.drawer.DrawerProxy.windowCreated(DrawerProxy.java:145)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivityWindows.windowCreated(TiActivityWindows.java:32)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at org.appcelerator.titanium.TiBaseActivity.windowCreated(TiBaseActivity.java:452)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at org.appcelerator.titanium.TiBaseActivity.onCreate(TiBaseActivity.java:528)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at org.appcelerator.titanium.TiActivity.onCreate(TiActivity.java:18)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
[ERROR] :  TiApplication:   ... 11 more
[INFO] :   Process: Sending signal. PID: 21167 SIG: 9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is resolved. The problem was I am using ANIMATION_FADE on Android, which is iOS-only. So the change of animation resolved my issue.